# "Interleaved rendering" in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, fragment-shader

P.S. Yes, I posted this [question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/12256) on Computer Graphics Stack Exchange. But posting there also in hope more people will see

#### Intro

I'm trying to render multi-channel images (more than 4 channels, for the purposes of feeding it to a Neural Network). Since OpenGL doesn't support it natively, I have multiple 4-channel render buffers, into which I render a corresponding portion of channels.

For example, I need multi-channel image of size `512 x 512 x 16`, in OpenGL I have 4 render buffers of size `512 x 512 x 4`. Now the problem is that the Neural Network expects the data with strides `512 x 512 x 16`, i.e. 16 values of channels of one pixel are followed by 16 values of channels from the next pixel. However currently I can efficiently read my 4 render buffers via 4 calls to `glReadPixels`, basically making the data having strides `4 x 512 x 512 x 4`. Manual reordering of data on the client side **will not suffice me** as it's too slow.

#### Main question

I've got an idea to render to a single 4-channel render buffer of size `512*4 x 512 x 4`, because stride-wise it's equivalent to `512 x 512 x 16`, we just treat a combination of 4 pixels in a row as a single pixel of 16-channel output image. Let's call it an "interleaved rendering"

But this requires me to magically adjust my fragment shader, so that every group of consequent 4 *fragments* would have exactly the same interpolation of vertex attributes. Is there any way to do that?

This bad illustration with 1 render buffer of `1024 x 512` 4-channel image, is an example of how it should be rendered. With that I can in 1 call `glReadPixels` extract the data with stride `512 x 512 x 8` [image]

EDIT: better pictures
What I have now (4 render buffers)
[image]

What I want to do natively in OpenGL (this image is done in Python offline)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this requires me to magically adjust my fragment shader, so that every group of consequent 4 fragments would have exactly the same interpolation of vertex attributes.

No, it would require a bit more than that. You have to fundamentally change how *rasterization* works.

Rendering at 4x the width is rendering at 4x the width. That means stretching the resulting primitives, relative to a square area. But that's not the effect you want. You need the rasterizer to rasterize at the original resolution, then replicate the rasterization products.

That's not possible.

From the comments:

> It just got to me, that I can try to get a 512 x 512 x 2 image of texture coordinates from vertex+fragment shaders, then stitch it with itself to make 4 times wider (thus we'll get the same interpolation) and from that form the final image

This is a good idea. You'll need to render whatever interpolated values you need to the original size texture, similar to how deferred rendering works. So it may be more than just 2 values. You could just store the `gl_FragCoord.xy` values, and then use them to compute whatever you need, but it's probably easier to store the interpolated values directly.

I would suggest doing a `texelFetch` when reading the texture, as you can specify exact integer texel coordinates. The integer coordinates you need can be computed from `gl_FragCoord` as follows:

```
ivec2 texCoords = ivec2(int(gl_FragCoord.x * 0.25f), int(gl_FragCoord.y));
```

Comment: Yeah, you edited the question to `512*4 x 512 x 4`,, but then it no longer stride wise equivalent to `512 x 512 x 16`. So I suppose the final image should be 4 times taller, not 4 times wider. But anyway, is there a way to directly make a compute shader with 16 contiguous output components?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: So, are the 16 elements not adjacent with each other? Because `glReadPixels` from a 512x2048 image will read 512 4-channel values, then 512 4-channel values, etc, row by row. If the stride between groups of 4 values is 512, then that would work, but you seemed to indicate that there is no stride between them. That the 16 values are contiguous for a particular pixel.

Comment: You are probably correct about 2048x512 then, I might confuse row/column major reads.

Comment: It just got to me, that I can try to get a `512 x 512 x 2`  image of texture coordinates from vertex+fragment shaders, then stitch it with itself to make 4 times wider (thus we'll get the same interpolation) and from that form the final image

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: I added some details to this idea.

Comment: Thank you a lot!